# Buttons are not being place where I tell them

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

So I was trying to place 10 buttons in a grid at the bottom of my frame (without using a layout manager) and for some reason I cannot figure out why this isn't working, I was wondering if anyone could help.

I should probably explain the code:

Basically I have just created a loop that stores a "while" in it, this while is repeated 3 times before ending and going back to the loop. After the while is finished, the Y changes by 85 to start a new layer for the next 3 buttons. The loop repeats 4 times to create 4 different layers of 10 buttons.

Thanks!

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Buttons.setButtons(frame, panel);
        Window.setFrame(frame, panel);
    }

}
```

**Buttons**

```
public class Buttons {
    
    private static JButton b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
    private static JButton equals;
    private static JButton minus;
    private static JButton plus; 
    private static int i = 0;
    private static int x = 10;
    private static int y = 140;
    
    private static JButton buttons[] = {b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9};
    
    public static void setButtons(JFrame frame, JPanel panel) {
        
        for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
            while (i < 3) {
                buttons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i)); 
                buttons[i].setBounds(x, y, 80, 80);
                x = x + 85; 
                buttons[i].setFocusable(false);
                buttons[i].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                panel.add(buttons[i]);
                i++;
            }
            y = y + 85; 
            x = 10;
        }
        
        System.out.print(y);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
    
}
```

**Window**

```
public class Window {

    public static void setFrame(JFrame frame, JPanel panel) {
        
        frame.setSize(370, 525);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        panel.setBounds(10, 140, 200, 200);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY); 
        frame.add(panel); 
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `while` loop, replace `i < 3` with `i < 10 && i < (i + 3)`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Maybe you *think* you're working without a layout manager because you haven't called `setLayout` on your `JFrame`, but in fact the `JFrame` gave itself a `BorderLayout` by default.

If you truly want to work without a layout manager,  add the line

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

in your setup code.

Comment: *"If you truly want to.."* ..to wreck the GUI ..*"..add the line `frame.setLayout(null);`"* Until you work out why that is sub-optimal advice, please stop offering advice on layouts that need to work across multiple platforms.

Comment: Working without a layout manager will cause many more problems than you can imagine.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks this works, and solved one of my problems. The other problem was that the "while" did not work after the second loop so I had to rewrite the loop system, here is the solution just in case you want to use it (don't use this, I'm a noob. Also don't be like me, use a layout manager.):

```
public class Buttons {

private static JButton b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
private static JButton dot;
private static JButton equals;
private static JButton minus;
private static JButton plus;
private static int count = 9;
private static int x = 10;
private static int y = 145;

private static JButton buttons[] = {b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9};

public static void setButtons(JFrame frame, JPanel panel) {
    
    for (int b = 3; b > 0; b--) {
        for (int i = 3; i > 0 ; i--) {
        buttons[count] = new JButton(Integer.toString(count)); 
        buttons[count].setBounds(x, y, 80, 80);
        x = x + 85; 
        buttons[count].setFocusable(false);
        buttons[count].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel.add(buttons[count]);
        count--;
        }
        y = y + 85; 
        x = 10;
    }
    
    dot = new JButton(".");
    dot.setBounds(x, y, 80, 80);
    dot.setFocusable(false);
    dot.setBackground(new Color(0, 200, 150));
    panel.add(dot);
    
    buttons[0] = new JButton("0");
    x = x + 85;
    buttons[0].setBounds(x, y, 80, 80);
    buttons[0].setFocusable(false);
    buttons[0].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    panel.add(buttons[0]);
    
    plus = new JButton("+");
    x = x + 85; 
    plus.setBounds(x, y, 80, 80); 
    plus.setFocusable(false);
    plus.setBackground(new Color(0, 200, 150));
    panel.add(plus);
    
    minus = new JButton("-");
    x = x + 85;
    minus.setBounds(x, y, 80, 80);
    minus.setFocusable(false);
    minus.setBackground(new Color(0, 200, 150));
    panel.add(minus); 
    
    equals = new JButton("=");
    y = 145;
    equals.setBounds(x, y, 80, 250);
    equals.setFocusable(false);
    equals.setBackground(new Color(240, 150, 50));
    panel.add(equals); 
    
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

}

Comment: Nobody should ever use this solution. The static variables are unnecessary. The null layout is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Java. The reason I'm not using a layout manager is due to the weird button placement I'm using (also I'm having difficulty using layout managers, this is my fault). Clearly I've also misunderstood the meaning of static so I'm gonna have to learn that. Thanks for the feedback, I'll edit the solution above and warn people that might consider using it.